# Is it possible to have destination view name configurable in spring mvc 3?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Code snippet is like this:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="/test")
public class TestController {
........        
    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getCreateForm(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute(new AccountBean());
        return "newtest";
    }
.........
```

"newtest" is the hard-coded view name. Is it possible to have it configured in an XML-style Spring config file? Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess the real question is how to configure properties of autodiscovered bean via XML.

You can do it by defining a `<bean>` with the same name as the autodiscovered one have (when the name of autodiscovered bean is not specified, it's assumed to be a classname with the first letter decapitalized):

```
@Controller 
@RequestMapping(value="/test") 
public class TestController { 
    private String viewName = "newtest";

    public void setViewName(String viewName) {
        this.viewName = viewName;
    }

    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET) 
    public String getCreateForm(Model model) { 
        model.addAttribute(new AccountBean()); 
        return viewName; 
    } 
}
```

.

```
<bean id = "testController" class = "TestController">
    <property name = "viewName" value = "oldtest" />
</bean>
```

Another option is to use `@Value` with SpEL expressions

```
@Value("#{testViewName}") private String viewName;
```

.

```
<bean id = "testViewName" class = "java.lang.String">
    <constructor-arg value = "oldtest" />
</bean>
```

or property placeholders

```
@Value("${testViewName}") private String viewName;
```

.

```
<context:property-placeholder location = "viewnames" />
```

`viewnames.properties`:

```
testViewName=oldtest
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, it is possible to return any string there. So yes - it can be configured.

Update: there are many ways to configure it, one of which (and my preference) being a combination of `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` and the `@Value` annotation, but that was already covered by axtavt.

Comment: sorry, I should've mentioned that what I really mean is to have it configured in an xml style Spring configuration file.